# springcloud eureka register center - how to use service-id instead of ip?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Now I have two peers, one is IP 192.168.1.2, another is IP 192.168.1.3, and it it referenced each other.

I have set the prefer-ip-address to true, in this case I should put real ip address in application file when in production environment.

It's not convenient to configure the ip addresses in application file.

The issue is I dont want to use ip address and hostname, is there a way to use the service-id or name to register each other ?

Thanks.

Comment: That is the point of eureka, can you show what you have tried? What dependencies you have? Are you using ribbon?

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for your response. I have tried hostname and ip address, I did not use the ribbon in eureka server, the url for each peer is http://192.168.1.2:7001/eureka,http://192.168.1.3:7001/eureka, if I use hosts instead of ip address, the server would be appper in unvailable replicas line.

Comment: for peers you have to use a hostname or ip